Steam SDK C++ crash on GetSteamID()
on Windows 64x, using steam api version 1.60 (the last one). With the following snippet, the game crashs on the function GetSteamID
if (SteamAPI_InitEx(nullptr)) {
  if (SteamUser()) {
    printf("SteamUser() is valid.\n");
    try {
      CSteamID steamID = SteamUser()->GetSteamID();
      printf("SteamID: %llu\n", steamID.ConvertToUint64());
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
      printf("Exception occurred: %s\n", e.what());
    }
  } else {
    printf("SteamUser() is nullptr.\n");
  }
  SteamAPI_Shutdown();
} else {
  printf("Failed to initialize Steam API.\n");
}

SteamUser() is NOT null, as I can see "SteamUser() is valid.\n". It is a valid ptr.
No exception, just a crash on that function GetSteamID()
With gdb, we can see in which function it crashes, which is the next function call after GetSteamID()
Thread 1 "MainThrd" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00007ffa5a3de225 in steamclient64!Steam_NotifyMissingInterface () from C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamclient64.dll

pointing my own steam client dll. It is up to date though.
I also tried using SteamAPI_Init() and SteamAPI_InitFlat() to load the API but I got the same result.
On Linux everything works fine.
Update: I followed advice from comments, I got the exact same crash behavior.
SteamErrMsg errMsg;
    if (SteamAPI_InitEx(&errMsg) == k_ESteamAPIInitResult_OK) {
        auto steamUser = SteamUser();
        if (steamUser) {
            LOG_ERROR(logger, "SteamUser() is valid.");
            try {
                CSteamID steamID = steamUser->GetSteamID();
                LOG_ERROR(logger, "SteamID: {}", steamID.ConvertToUint64());
            } catch (const std::exception &e) {
                LOG_ERROR(logger, "Exception occurred: {}", e.what());
            }
        } else {
            LOG_ERROR(logger, "SteamUser() is nullptr.");
        }
        SteamAPI_Shutdown();
    } else {
        LOG_ERROR(logger, "Failed to initialize Steam API.");
    }


Calling SteamUser() twice is probably not good practice - I'd rather store the returned value in a local var and then hit the if statement, but I guess it should not err.

SteamAPI_InitEx returns k_ESteamAPIInitResult_OK if it's ok or an error code as specified by ESteamAPIInitResult if it's not ok. Your first check is therefore wrong.

@TedLyngmo yep you are right, my example was wrong (which wasn't in my code). Anyway I got same error with updated code (tested).

Solution: Using MSVC instead of MinGW resolved the problem. steam_api.dll was probably built with MSVC, using another compiler will cause intern bugs.

I'm not sure whether that's an answer/solution or an extra detail on the configuration or symptoms. If it's the latter, you can edit the question to add detail as it becomes apparent, and do away with this answer.
